# Trying to get repeating pattern in .gitignore

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I've got repeating sections I want to consolidate with wildcards somehow and I'm not a regex guy. I tried what I thought was obvious (replace ClassLib/bin/beta4 with /ClassLib/bin/*, etc) but id did not work.

Ideas?

```
ClassLib/bin/beta4
DataAccess/bin/beta4
ClassLib/bin/beta4
CSSFriendly/bin/beta4
LINQToSql/bin/beta4

ClassLib/bin/beta.svcc.com
DataAccess/bin/beta.svcc.com
ClassLib/bin/beta.svcc.com
CSSFriendly/bin/beta.svcc.com
LINQToSql/bin/beta.svcc.com
```

Comment: what about `*/bin/*` ?

Comment: @eis you should turn that into an answer

Comment: I don't want to exclude all bin directories, I just want the ones that meet the pattern above.

Answer (score 1):

Try `*/bin/*`

(added some text so I can submit this)

Edit:

ok, if not all the bin directories, how about

```
*/bin/beta4
*/bin/beta.svcc.com
```

if that's not the case either, you should really clarify what do you want to exclude and what to include.

Comment: It still is to general. I would not have put all that extra stuff in my question if I wanted to ignore it.  Good to see the answer voted up.  It's a nice day (just not the right answer)

Comment: @PeterKellner edited the answer. Though you really should clarify what it is exactly that you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not entirely clear from the question what you what to exclude and what *not*, but if it's exactly those five bin directories, try the following.

```
ClassLib/bin
DataAccess/bin
CSSFriendly/bin
LINQToSql/bin
```

Comment: I wonder what's the difference between `ClassLib/bin` and `ClassLib/bin` :)

Comment: @eis Yeah, just copy-pasted it from above... editing the redundant line away

Answer (score 0):

*ClassLib/bin/* seems to have worked 
etc.